# Algebra-precalculus gmat exam question based on time, speed and work

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If two pipes can fill a cistern of capacity $1,00,000$ liters in $20$ hours and $30$ hours respectively, find the time taken by both of them to fill $75,000$ liters of water in it.

What I did:

Work done by two pipes together= LCM of $20$ and $30$= $600$ units
Work done by Pipe 1= $30$ units
Work done by Pipe 2= $20$ units
Time taken by both of them to do the work= $75000/50$
But this is not the right answer
I will be really grateful if anyone will help me out with this one

Comment: Is that supposed to be $1,000,000$ litres or $100,000$ litres for the first tank?

Comment: When two things, or people, work together their **speeds** add.  The first pipe fills the 100,000 liter cistern in 20 hours so fills at 100,000/20= 5000 liters per hour.  The second pipe fills the 100,000 liter cistern in 30 hours so fills at 100,000/30= 3,333 and 1/3 liters per hour.  So the two together will fill the cistern at 5000+ 3333 and 1/3= 8,333 and 1/3 liters per hour and will fill the  75,000 liter cistern in 75000/8333 and 1/3= 9 hours.

Comment: By the way, 20= 2*2*5 and 30= 2*3*5 so the LCM of 20 and 30 is 2*2*3*5= 60 **not** 600.  Also 20 and 30 are times in hours, not "work done".

Comment: Thanks @user247327 You made it look so easy :)

Comment: I suggest you try labeling your variables.  i.e. $100k\ liters$ in $20\ hours = 5k \frac {liters}{hour}.$  Two pipes working together leads to $(5k + 3\frac 13k)\frac {liters}{hour}\cdot x\ hours = 75k\ liters$  If you keep track of your units, you will be able to see if you are applying the correct formula.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Together they need $x=\frac{600}{50}=12$ hours to fill $100,000$ liters. The equation to obtain the result is

$$\left(\frac1{20}+\frac1{30}\right)\cdot x=1 \ \textrm{cistern}$$

Now solve for $x$. Then it is easy to calculate how many hours they need to fill the cistern with $75,000$ liters.

Comment: Where did $50$ and $60$ come from?  The fill times are $20$ and $30$ hours

Comment: Good question. Answer: I don´t know. One reason could be that it is too late.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to compute the flow from each pipe.  I am assuming the cistern is $1,000,000$ liters based on the commas in the question, not $100,000$ based on the number of zeros.  The first supplies $\frac {1,000,000 \text{liters}}{20 \text{hours}}=50,000 \frac {\text{liters}}{\text{hour}}$  The second supplies $\frac {100,000}3 \frac {\text{liters}}{\text{hour}}$.  Add these and divide into $75,000$ to get $0.9$ hours

Comment: After following your comment I get 9 hours for 75000 liters.

Comment: @callculus:  It can't be $9$ as the first pipe can fill $75,000$ in $1.5$ hours all by itself.  That comes because I took the first tank to be a million liters because of the commas, not a hundred thousand because of the number of zeros..

Comment: If you assume a capacity of $1,000,000$ liters then I agree with you.